# Spring 3 (SWS2): difference between <context:component-scan> and <sws:annotation-driven>

Tags: spring, spring-ws

When trying a simple Web Service Hello World example with just one `@Endpoint` annotated class, the Endpoint is not registered when using the `<sws:annotation-driven/>` namespace.

However, by adding the usual `<context:component-scan>`, everything works well, the Endpoint-class is registered correctly.
This is only true for the `@Endpoint` annotation, all other annotations (`@RequestPayload`, `@ResponsePayload`, `@PayloadRoot`) will be registered by the sws-namespace as expected.

Should the `@Endpoint` annotation not be processed by this namespace as well?

```
<beans>
   <!-- works for all annotations except @Endpoint -->
    <sws:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- when activated, @Endpoint is registered correctly <context:component-scan/> -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you tell me the address to this example? I am having hard time finding good Spring WS 2 tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known SWS bug: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWS-702.

Comment: I saw this bug-report, but Arjen's comment on 19/May seemed to me to indicate an other bug - my endpoint does not implement any interface, nor am I using aop-proxies (at least intentionally).

Answer (score 2):

For now use both as in:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.coral.project.endpoints"/>

<sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"/>
```

this finds both @Endpoint and @PayloadRoot,@ResponsePayload annotations.
This is the way they tell you to do it in Spring-WS reference:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html#tutorial.implementing.endpoint

Comment: True, however there it's said: ...we also instruct Spring-WS to use annotation-driven endpoints, with the <sws:annotation-driven> element... so I understand that the context:cmp-scan was only used for registering components "outside" the sws-domain.

Comment: So is this a bug or by-design? I am having the same issue and this answer resolves it. It is just not this way in the examples Pivotal has in their spring documentation. [See the 5.4. Endpoints section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html)

Comment: and can you explain me where this marhaller are sets  ?

Comment: It's a JAXB marshaller that you need to define and implement. Please see Spring's doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html
and an example: http://thoughtforge.net/610/marshalling-xml-with-spring-ws-and-jaxb/
and also: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: but I am not interested in jaxb. I want to know where spring-ws use this marshaller. In example which you post there is nothing about spring-ws mapping (it is mention in comments)