# Spring ws endpoint mapped twice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I'm getting this error for the given endpoint class:

`Cannot map endpoint [public org.iaws.data.model.Theaters iaws.ws.soap.resources.TheaterEndpoint.getTheaters(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException] on registration key [{http://iaws/ws/contractfirst/example}data]: there's already endpoint [public org.iaws.data.model.Theaters iaws.ws.soap.resources.TheaterEndpoint.getTheaters(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException] mapped`

Why the endpoint is mapped twice?

```
@Endpoint
public class TheaterEndpoint {

private final static String NAMESPACE = "http://soap/ws/contractfirst/example";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE, localPart = "data")
@Namespace(prefix="dt", uri = NAMESPACE)
@ResponsePayload
public Theaters getTheaters(
        @XPathParam("/dt:data/dt:movieId") final String movieId,
        @XPathParam("/dt:data/dt:location") final String location)
        throws SQLException {
    TheaterSearch data = new TheaterSearch(movieId, location);
    if (data.getMovieId() == null && data.getLocation() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else {
        if (data.getMovieId() == null) {
            return db.getTheaters(data.getLocation());
        } else {
            if (data.getLocation() == null) {
                return db.getTheatersForMovie(data.getMovieId());
            } else {
                Theaters theaters = db.getTheatersForMovie(
                        data.getMovieId(), data.getLocation());
                return theaters;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to fix a similar issue and following worked.

In the MessageDispatcherServlet (spring-ws-servlet.xml in my case), I had a bean created for the endpoint class along with having a component-scan. **Remove the bean**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- 
    enables support for endpoint annotation, as per spring docs. 
    Forums ask to use this along with component scan. See SWS Bug 702 
    <link>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198644/spring-3-sws2-difference-between-contextcomponent-scan-and-swsannotation</link>
    -->
    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pkg.endpoint" />

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="holiday" 
                      portTypeName="HumanResource" 
                      locationUri="/holidayService/"
                      targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schema/holiday.xsd"/>
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <!-- REMOVE THIS BEAN -->
    <bean id="holidayEndpoint" class="com.pkg.endpint.HolidayEndpoint" />

</beans>
```